# Why does WSL show files that don't exist in cmd or Windows File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hidden-file

Why does the `ls -l` command in WSL return files and directories that don't appear in the Windows File Explorer or using the `dir` cmd command?

Output from the `ll` (`ls -l`) command in WSL2 Debian 11:

```
user@computer:/mnt/c$ ll
ls: Config.Msi: Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'DumpStack.log.tmp': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'hiberfil.sys': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'pagefile.sys': Permission denied
ls: PerfLogs: Permission denied
ls: Recovery: Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'swapfile.sys': Permission denied
ls: 'System Volume Information': Permission denied
total 388
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user   4096 Dec 25  2020 '$Recycle.Bin'
dr-xr-xr-x 1 user user   4096 Jun 16 22:13 '$WinREAgent'
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user user 395268 Jul 10  2015  bootmgr
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user user      1 Oct 30  2015  BOOTNXT
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user user     80 Oct 21  2018  bootTel.dat
d--x--x--x 1 user user   4096 Jun 30 11:51  Config.Msi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user     12 Jul 10  2015 'Documents and Settings' -> /mnt/c/Users
-????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ?  DumpStack.log.tmp
-????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ?  hiberfil.sys
-????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ?  pagefile.sys
d--x--x--x 1 user user   4096 Dec  7  2019  PerfLogs
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user   4096 Feb 14 13:37  ProgramData
dr-xr-xr-x 1 user user   4096 Jun 30 14:07 'Program Files'
dr-xr-xr-x 1 user user   4096 Jun 30 14:56 'Program Files (x86)'
d--x--x--x 1 user user   4096 Mar 13 10:58  Recovery
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user user     27 Nov 30  2016  Settings.ini
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user   4096 Sep  2  2021  Strawberry
-????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ?  swapfile.sys
d--x--x--x 1 user user   4096 Jun 30 11:51 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user   4096 Sep 21  2019  temp
dr-xr-xr-x 1 user user   4096 Dec 25  2020  Users
drwxrwxrwx 1 user user   4096 Apr  3 13:38  WCH.CN
dr-xr-xr-x 1 user user   4096 Jun 16 22:36  Windows
```

Output from the `dir /a:h` command in the Windows 10 command prompt:

```
C:\>dir /a:d
 C volume doesn't have a name
 Volume serial number is 5DFB-D456

 Directories from C:\

25/12/2020  02:49    <DIR>          $Recycle.Bin
16/06/2022  22:13    <DIR>          $WinREAgent
30/06/2022  11:51    <DIR>          Config.Msi
10/07/2015  14:21    <JUNCTION>     Documents and Settings [C:\Users]
07/12/2019  11:14    <DIR>          PerfLogs
30/06/2022  14:07    <DIR>          Program Files
30/06/2022  14:56    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
14/02/2022  14:37    <DIR>          ProgramData
13/03/2022  11:58    <DIR>          Recovery
02/09/2021  22:29    <DIR>          Strawberry
30/06/2022  11:51    <DIR>          System Volume Information
21/09/2019  13:37    <DIR>          temp
25/12/2020  21:12    <DIR>          Users
03/04/2022  13:38    <DIR>          WCH.CN
16/06/2022  22:36    <DIR>          Windows
               0 file(s)                0 bytes
              15 dir(s)  51 495 235 584 free bytes
```

Screenshot from the Windows File Explorer showing files on the C volume when the "Show hidden files" option is ticked:
[image: Screenshot from the Windows File Explorer]

As you can see WSL shows more files like `bootmgr`, `bootTel.dat` or `pagefile.sys` while the `dir /a:h` command show more directories than the File Explorer like `Config.Msi`, `Recovery` or `$Recycle.Bin`.

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of those items also have the `S` (System) attribute, which among other things means "hidden, but more". You could see them using `dir/a` or `dir/a:s`, or by disabling the option "Hide protected operating system files".

Comment: Are those created by WSL or Windows?